# Laravel 5.2 : One database field many values seperated with comma

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2, I am stuck in a case,Where i have one db field `product_specs` and 5 form `input` inserting their values to that same `product_specs` database field.

My question is that how can i add comma to values and then insert it to the database field `product_specs`.

Then i will be able to use php function `explode()` to remove the comma and use the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) function?

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Answer (score -1):

just concatenate and insert on db ?

```
$product_specs = $value1 . ',' . $value2 . ',' .....;
//insert $product_specs on db field product_specs
```

then when need fetch the data and implode the previous answer

hope it helps if thats your question

Comment: The `implode()` function is the function is the best solution...
Please check the above answer !